# Kind of reflection in C++

Tags: c++, oop, reflection

I am trying to implement limited `reflection` in C++, so that I could be able to call `getter` and `setter` on the objects stored. Here is what I have done so far

### Main Code

```
#ifndef REFLECTION_MANAGER_HPP_
#define REFLECTION_MANAGER_HPP_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


template <class Owner, class IOType> 
class SingleProperty {
public:
  typedef IOType    (Owner::*get_func_t)(); 
  typedef void    (Owner::*set_func_t)( IOType Value );

  inline SingleProperty(get_func_t Getter, set_func_t Setter ): m_Getter(Getter), m_Setter(Setter) {
  }
  get_func_t        m_Getter;
  set_func_t        m_Setter;
};

class ReflectionManager {
public:
  static ReflectionManager& Instance() {
    static ReflectionManager instance;
    return instance;
  }

  template <class Owner, class IOType> 
  void RegisterProperty(  std::string class_name, 
                          std::string property_name, 
                          typename SingleProperty<Owner, IOType>::get_func_t GetFn, 
                          typename SingleProperty<Owner, IOType>::set_func_t SetFn)  {
    SingleProperty<Owner, IOType>* pProperty = new SingleProperty<Owner, IOType>(GetFn, SetFn );
    m_class_memeber_map[class_name][property_name] = pProperty;
  }

  template <class Owner> void put(std::string key, void *value, std::string class_name = NULL ) {
    Owner *ptr = reinterpret_cast<Owner*>(value);
    std::map<std::string, std::map< std::string, void*> >::iterator pos = m_class_memeber_map.find(class_name);
    if ( pos == m_class_memeber_map.end()) {
      return; // handle the error
    }
    for ( std::map< std::string, void*>::iterator itr = pos->second.begin(); itr != pos->second.end(); ++itr ) {
      SingleProperty<Owner,std::string> *ptr = (SingleProperty<Owner,std::string> *)itr->second;
      (ptr->*m_Getter)();
    }
  }
private:
  ReflectionManager() {
  }
  ReflectionManager(ReflectionManager const&); 
  void operator=(ReflectionManager const&);

  std::map<std::string, std::map< std::string, void*> > m_class_memeber_map;

};

#endif
```

### Calling Code

This will be called as follows

```
ReflectionManager::Instance().RegisterProperty<Person, std::string>("Person", "m_name", &Person::GetName, &Person::SetName);
  ReflectionManager::Instance().RegisterProperty<Person, std::string>("Person", "m_dept", &Person::GetDept, &Person::SetDept);
  ReflectionManager::Instance().RegisterProperty<Person, int>("Person", "m_age", &Person::GetAge, &Person::SetAge);

  Person p1;
  p1.SetName("Avinash");
  p1.SetDept("Gemfire Native Client");
  p1.SetAge(34);

  ReflectionManager::Instance().put<Person>( "key1", &p1, "Person");
```

I have stored the `getter` and `setter` in the `map`, but in `put` function I am not able to call it since I donot know the type.

### Problem

Basically How do i implement now the for loop `for ( std::map< std::string, void*>::iterator itr = pos->second.begin(); itr != pos->second.end(); ++itr )` in which I want to iterate over each element and call the respective `getter` and `setter` methods.

I tried this but does not work.

```
(ptr->*((itr->second).m_Getter))();
```

**Another Approach I found Would appreciate Comments**

```
  template <class Owner, class IOType> 
  void RegisterProperty(  std::string class_name, 
    std::string property_name, 
    typename SingleProperty<Owner, IOType>::get_func_t GetFn, 
    typename SingleProperty<Owner, IOType>::set_func_t SetFn)  {

      SingleProperty<Owner, IOType>* pProperty = new SingleProperty<Owner, IOType>(GetFn, SetFn );
      m_class_memeber_map[class_name][property_name] = pProperty;
      m_property_type_map[class_name].push_back(std::make_pair(property_name, TypeName<IOType>::get()));

  }

  template <class Owner> void put(std::string key, void *value, std::string class_name = NULL ) {
    Owner *pOwner  = reinterpret_cast<Owner*>(value);
    std::map<std::string, std::map< std::string, void*> >::iterator pos = m_class_memeber_map.find(class_name);

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > vector_property_map = m_property_type_map.find(class_name)->second;
    for ( std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >::iterator itr = vector_property_map.begin();itr != vector_property_map.end(); ++itr ) {
        std::map< std::string, void*>::iterator pos_getter_setter_fn = pos->second.find(itr->first);
        if ( itr->second == "int" ) {
          SingleProperty<Owner,int> *ptr = (SingleProperty<Owner, int> *)pos_getter_setter_fn->second;
          (pOwner->*(ptr->m_Getter))();
        } else if ( itr->second == "string" ) {
          SingleProperty<Owner,std::string> *ptr = (SingleProperty<Owner, std::string> *)pos_getter_setter_fn->second;
          (pOwner->*(ptr->m_Getter))();
        } 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you simply trying to use `ReflectionManager::Instance()` as a collection of elements of some arbitrary type?  I don't see from your "This will be called as follows" code why you need reflection.  Basically, I can't yet see why a `std::map<string, Person>` is unsuitable.

Comment: Because Person will be user class , who will provide me respective getter and setter methods. Which I plan to save and later use for other purposes

Comment: itr->second still points to a `void` in `(ptr->*((itr->second).m_Getter))();` not to a function pointer. You'll either need to cast it or store function pointers in the map (wich won't work for what you're intending).

Comment: What do you want to happen when someone calls `ReflectionManager::Instance().put<Person>("m_age", &p1, "notveryold");`?

Comment: I want to iterate over all the setter and getter stored in a map against third parameter

Comment: It's not clear what your `put` function is supposed to do. Call all the property getters and setters, and then what? Why do you need a `reinterpret_cast` there? Do you realise that you shadow the `Owner* ptr` in the loop with another `ptr`?

Comment: Iterate doing what exactly with each stored getter and setter?

Comment: `std::string class_name = NULL ` => that is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These pointers are **pointers to function members** of `Owner` type:

```
get_func_t m_Getter;
set_func_t m_Setter;
```

Why do you try to call them giving `SingleProperty<>` pointer as object?

```
Owner *ptr = reinterpret_cast<Owner*>(value);
for ( std::map< std::string, void*>::iterator itr = pos->second.begin();
   itr != pos->second.end(); ++itr )
{
  SingleProperty<Owner,std::string> *ptr = 
      (SingleProperty<Owner,std::string> *)itr->second;
  // Here is the flaw, you are trying to call m_Getter from SingleProperty object
  // pointer, but it must be Owner pointer!
  (ptr->*m_Getter)();
}
```

Also you have to properly pass type of property as template parameter `IOType`.
I'm not sure what do you try to do with this function and what is the effect of calling getters with discarded return type, but from abstract syntax point of view it shall be like this:

```
template <class Owner, class IOType> void put(const std::string& key, Owner* value,
    const std::string& class_name = "")
{
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, void*> >::iterator pos =
        m_class_memeber_map.find(class_name);

    if(pos == m_class_memeber_map.end())
    {
       return; // handle the error
    }

    for(std::map<std::string, void*>::iterator itr = pos->second.begin();
       itr != pos->second.end(); ++itr)
    {

        SingleProperty<Owner,IOType> *ptr = 
          static_cast<SingleProperty<Owner, IOType>*>(itr->second);
        (value->*(ptr->m_Getter))(); // return IOType discarded?!?!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just one question is there a way to avoid passing exact type like here we are passing std::string as second template parameter

Comment: This still has a fundamental flaw: you don't know the type of property and casting it to `(SingleProperty<Owner,std::string> *)` is UB.

Comment: @aleguna I just copy-pasted the code from OP's question, but actually you are right, `put()` shall be also parametrized by `IOType`. Hope this is not production code, just concept-proof or smthg.